# How to serve bower_components in Node.js using feathersjs?

Tags: node.js, express, bower, feathersjs

I try serve bower_components directory who's a location is in root path to include jQuery and Bootstrap frameworks. Node has default serve a public directory. Below is my snippet code, but is not working. I have correctly installed bootstrap framework and jQuery. I used a bower. What I do wrong?

```
app.use('/', feathers.static(app.get('public')))
.use('jquery', feathers.static(__dirname + '../../bower_components'))
.use('bootstrap', feathers.static(__dirname + '../../bower_components'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it this way you have to link to the actual folder within `bower_components`:

```
const path = require('path');
const bowerComponents = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'bower_components');

app.use('/', feathers.static(app.get('public')))
  .use('/jquery', feathers.static(path.join(bowerComponents, 'jquery'))
  .use('/bootstrap', feathers.static(path.join(bowerComponents, 'bootstrap')));
```

Comment: Thanks Daff, I managed in this way:

app.use('/', feathers.static(app.get('public')))
.use(feathers.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'bower_components')));